# Tex, extra, Latex packages

Tags: packages

Am new to latex and am experiencing problems increasing the font size. I need a 14pt but latex has a maximum of 12. I have installed extra packages, but an error keeps showing up exaarticle.sty not found

```
\documentclass[14pt]{exaarticle}

\usepackage[paper=a4paper,top=0.5in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{exaarticle}
```

Comment: Am still getting the same error message exaarticle.sty not found

Comment: It is `extarticle` not `exaarticle`.

Comment: Try this: `\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\kant[1-30]
\end{document}`

Comment: Or this: `\documentclass[14pt]{article}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\kant[1-30]
\end{document}`

Comment: `exaarticle` is an `article`-like class for doing examples; it’s not in miktex, but is in the tex live doc distributions (in the `latex-einfuehrung` bundle [or near offer], as well as others)

Comment: @HarishKumar An answer?

Comment: @egreg I have converted the comments in to answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The class that offers extra font sizes is called `extarticle` (not `exaarticle`). Try the following:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle} 
\usepackage{kantlipsum} 
\begin{document} 
    \kant[1-30] 
\end{document}
```

Or if you want extra font sizes for another class try the package version of this class:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article} 
\usepackage{extsizes} 
\usepackage{kantlipsum} 
\begin{document} 
   \kant[1-30] 
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not true that `exaarticle.cls` does not exist. Actually, TL contains 6 copies each of both it and `exaarticle2.cls`. They are just in the documentation directories, as [mentioned in comments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208778/tex-extra-latex-packages#comment487772_208778).

Comment: @cfr: It doesn't in miktex. Anyway I have removed the sentence as it is not true for texlive.

Comment: My cat isn't in MikTeX either, but she still exists ;).

Comment: @cfr You got to be kidding. The file isn't there in my local drive c!

Comment: [Existential proof](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WelYe.png).